# How to handle query in local MongoDB database, while I am using MongoDB Atlas Search?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-atlas-search

I am looking at the `MongoDB Atlas Search`. It seems only work in the `MongoDB Atlas Cloud`.

For dev purposes, while I run the app in the local environment and use the local MongoDB server, how these `Atlas Search` query will work?

I find 2 inefficient solutions.

1. I put a flag to determine if the app is in the `dev` environment or `production` environment. But this is not an ideal solution.
2. Each developer should use a `MongoDB Atlas Free Tier` for dev purposes.

Is there any better approach for `MongoDB Atlas Search` in the dev environment?

Comment: I like solution one. But yes, I recommend a free tier cluster or very small cluster for dev.

Comment: Right now, we are using the free tier for dev. Thanks

Comment: Awesome. Happy to help if you have any troubles with the Atlas Search product. I like it a lot.

Comment: Thats awesome. Can I have your mail please?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like MongoDB has dismissed the idea of adding local support for Atlas Search. https://feedback.mongodb.com/forums/924868-atlas-search/suggestions/38786944-please-support-on-prem-installations?_ga=2.41811874.1254500888.1642099818-1739591939.1642099808

Answer (score 3):

The first one is not a real solution. You need to use Atlas for development and testing.

I am unaware of any other way to obtain the equivalent functionality. The Atlas Search is proprietary.